# How do I reverse route a static file?

Tags: java, playframework

At first I had this link to a twitter icon:

```
@{'/public/images/twitter-icon.png'/}
```

But now I want to show a Twitter-, Facebook- or LinkedIn icon depending on type. So, I created a FastTag that takes the type as a parameter and the code looks like this:

```
In the view:
#{myApp.icon contact.type/}

FastTag Java Code:
String type = (String) args.get("arg");
out.print("/public/images/" + type + "-icon.png");
```

It works fine. But, on our build server we run the app with a prefix on the uri like this

```
http://ourdomain.com/appname/...
```

Obviously /public/images... won't work here. So I figured I have to ask the Router for the proper address. I've tried the following with no success:

```
Router.reverse("/public/images/" + type + "-icon.png");
Router.reverse("/public/");
Router.reverse("staticDir:public");
```

All three result in a NoRouteFoundException. How can I get the correct route for my icons?

In the routes file I have the default route for static files

```
GET     /public/        staticDir:public
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
String imageUrl = Router.reverse(VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("public/images/" + type + "-icon.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Router.reverse be used generate URL form one action!
maybe you can  define a route which include your app name  and route one action eg:

GET     /appname/public/        TestController.test

now,you can use

Router.reverse("TestController.test")

get the URL.

Comment: Any chance you could try and expand on this answer a little? It doesn't really say anything of use right now :/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to do something like:

```
GET      /img/     staticDir:public/images
```

And in the template just:

```
out.print("/img/" + type + "-icon.png");
```

Comment: That won't work in our case where we have play running in an url like this: http://ourdomain.com/appname/img/<type>-icon.png. You don't get /appname/img/<type>-icon.png just /img/<type>-icon.png