# Simple vs. double quotes in a playframework template tag (1.2.4)

Tags: templates, playframework

If I use the url tag with double quotes:

```
@{"/public/images/blue.png"}
```

I get this error:

```
No route able to invoke action CONTROLLERNAME./public/images/blue.png was found
```

While everything works when using single quotes:

```
@{'/public/images/blue.png'}
```

Maybe I've been too much head into the code and there's something stupid I'm not seeing?

In the [template tag documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates), nor in particular in the [`@` template tag documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#Actionsor), I could not see a mention to different semantic meaning of single and double quotes...

In groovy double quotes are [`templetable strings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy) but still this does not seem to explain why it's failing, and if it is a known behaviour it should be written extremely loud in the doc - it took me quite a good deal of time to understand what the issue was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler` has the follow method for executing `@{..}` and `@@{..}`:

```
@Override
void action(boolean absolute) {
    String action = parser.getToken().trim();
    if (action.trim().matches("^'.*'$")) {
        if (absolute) {
            print("\tout.print(__reverseWithCheck_absolute_true("+action+"));");
        } else {
            print("\tout.print(__reverseWithCheck_absolute_false("+action+"));");
        }
    } else {
        if (!action.endsWith(")")) {
            action = action + "()";
        }
        if (absolute) {
            print("\tout.print(actionBridge._abs()." + action + ");");
        } else {
            print("\tout.print(actionBridge." + action + ");");
        }
    }
    markLine(parser.getLine());
    println();
}
```

The `action` string here is everything in between `@{` and `}`. And it's called with `absolute` set to false if you use `@{..}`. The `__reverseWithCheck_absolute_true/false` are the methods needed to find the templates. But if the action doesn't match the regex `"^'.*'$"` (which happens when you use anything else than single qoutes), then it tries to invoke the `action` as a method  of your Controller.

I don't really understand the part where it tries to find the Controller action though, but I believe that's what is throwing the error. The `actionBridge` is an instance of the `ActionBridge` class defined in `play.templates.GroovyTemplate`, if you want to take a look at it ...

Comment: you nailed it! it is not something "generic" about template tags, it is really the way the _that_ template tag is implemented. I had never checked how template tag parsing really work, and I'm a little suprised of this finding, but I'm guessing this is an exception. Anyway, this behaviour should definitely be explained in the documentation!!!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't put a full path string between `@{}` so it should not work at all. You should simply put directly the `"/public/images/blue.png"` in your code.

`@{}` is used for reverse routing the url of a given Controller and action.

And if you really want to check if the file exists, you could have your own tag.

for the `#{script /}` tag, this is how the "file exists" check is done:

*framework/templates/tags/script.tag*

```
%{
    (_arg ) && (_src = _arg);

    if (!_src) {
        throw new play.exceptions.TagInternalException("src attribute cannot be empty for script tag");
    }
    _src = "/public/javascripts/" + _src
    try {
        _abs = play.mvc.Router.reverseWithCheck(_src, play.Play.getVirtualFile(_src), false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new play.exceptions.TagInternalException("File not found: " + _src);
    }
}%
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"#{if _id} id="${_id}"#{/if}#{if _charset} charset="${_charset}"#{/if}  src="${_abs}"></script>
```

Comment: putting a path in a url `@` template tag not only works, but it's the only way to make your static files accessible if you deploy your application as a JBoss war - which is the reason that I have for using it. It's not in the official doc, but in some comments and in SO too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345613/how-do-i-reverse-route-a-static-file

Comment: ...and in any case this wouldn't be an answer to my question ;-)